# Create macro with no effect, even if used exlusively in a line

Tags: macros

I have an `inlinetodo` macro/command that is defined depending on a toggle:

```
\nottoggle{disableAnnotations}{
    \NewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{[TODO: #1]}{}}
}{
    \NewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{}
}
```

As you see, the command does not make anything if `disableAnnotations` is enabled. But that is not entirely true. If I have

```
This is the first line.
\inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!}
Last line here.
```

Then there will be a larger space between "…first line." and "Last line…".

How can I avoid the space, so that the result will be equal to

```
This is the first line.
Last line here.
```

if annotations are disabled?

Comment: That's the usual missing % at the line endings, which will avoid them acting as space. Try with `\inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!}%`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat for more information

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Silly me! I did not take `inline` todo as meaning what it says. I have tried a similar command with `\ignorespaces` but it gobbles one one side. I will delete my prior comment.

Comment: @rallg No worries, given that the question neither has a mwe nor shows the output, it is a bit hard to picture :)

Comment: I think this question does ask the same, but the only answer provided is `\@bsphack\@esphack`, whereas Ulrike's answer here lists several options, from which I went with a particular one that I refined to `\ifhmode \unskip{} \fi`. And from what I can tell `\@bsphack\@esphack` has some issues if it appears right after another `\@bsphack\@esphack` sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends what you want exactly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is the first line. Last line here.

\medskip
\NewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{}

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!}Last line here.

This is the first line.\inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

\medskip
\RenewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{\ignorespaces}

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!}Last line here.

This is the first line.\inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

\medskip
\RenewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{\unskip}

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!}Last line here.

This is the first line.\inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.


\medskip
\makeatletter \RenewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{\@bsphack\@esphack} 
\makeatother 


This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

This is the first line. \inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!}Last line here.

This is the first line.\inlinetodo{Explain the issue here!} Last line here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I went with `\NewDocumentCommand \inlinetodo {m}{\ifhmode \unskip{} \fi}`.

Comment: Since this question will probably be closed as a duplicate, it would be good to add this answer to the original question, since such a comparison is still missing there.